# How to track screens through time?

Tags: c++, winapi, multiple-monitors

I'm trying to create a software that will provide statistics on my mouse usage(basically a glorified mouse hook). To know which display the mouse is currently sitting on, i can get a MONITORINFOEX struct through the MonitorFromPoint function. I'm trying to handle the case where monitors are added and removed through time.

For instance if on day 0 i have 2 screens (side by side) i can list them and store their location and bounding box and their relative location. If on day 1 i swap their location, i want to know that display left became display right and vice versa. Whereas if i identify the screens uniquely with their pos and resolution i would think that from day 0 to day 1 nothing changed (since both displays can have the same resolution).

I'm looking at the MONITORINFOEXA::szDevice (https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmonitorinfoexa) field. I can't find information on the uniqueness of this identifier, if both screens are the same models will they be the same ? Are they the same over time ? Is there another way to uniquely identify monitor through time ?